# SQL Query Syntax Error using select & <> with 2 columns

Tags: sql

I got a table with 2 columns here.

```
| column1 | column2 |
| A       | 1       |
| B       | 1       |
| C       | 2       |
| D       | 1       |
```

I'm trying to execute a SELECT query that: 
Selects a value FROM Column 2 WHILE Column 2 doesn't have the same value in a row which has Column 1 = "A"

```
SELECT column2 from mytable and column2 <> (SELECT * FROM mytable where column1 = 'A');
```

Basically I'm trying to execute a query that returns column1 values only when column2 is valued at "2" here.
But the project I'm making will be having column2 values random so I should use only columns names

Sorry if that's too confusing!

Comment: *Selects a value FROM Column 2...* and *returns column1 values .....* what do you really want to return?

Comment: Little unclear what you're looking for.  First, you say that you want the values from `Column2` where the value of `Column1 ` doesn't equal 'A' but you also say you want the values when `Column2` is valued at '2'.  Just need a little clarity, perhaps add the expected result from your attempted query.

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
  select t1.* from mytable t1
  where not exists ( select 1 from mytable t2 where t2.column2=t1.column2 and column1='A')
```

or use `not in`

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 where t1.column2 not in ( select column2 from table_name where column1='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery of your query returns multiple values. So you have to use `NOT IN` instead of `<>`:

```
SELECT column2 
FROM mytable 
WHERE column2 NOT IN (SELECT column2 FROM mytable WHERE column1 = 'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `join`, for example:

```
select t1.column2
from mytable t1 left join 
(select distinct t2.column2 from mytable t2 where t2.column1='A') t3 on t1.column2=t3.column2
where t3.column2 is null
```